# Missing reference for ADO.Net in SSIS script C#

Tags: c#, ssis, ado.net, dts

I use this code in a console app and it works. (from MSDN)

> ```
> using System;  
> using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;  
> using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;  
> using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;  
>   
> namespace Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Samples  
> {  
>   class Program  
>   {  
>     static void Main(string[] args)  
>     { 
>                  Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package package = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package();
>                 Executable e = package.Executables.Add("STOCK:PipelineTask");
>                 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost thMainPipe = (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost)e;
>                 MainPipe dataFlowTask = (MainPipe)thMainPipe.InnerObject;
>
>                 // The Application object will be used to obtain the CreationName  
>                 //  of a PipelineComponentInfo from its PipelineComponentInfos collection.  
>                 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
>
>                 // Add a first ADO NET source to the data flow.  
>                 //  The CreationName property requires an Application instance.  
>                 IDTSComponentMetaData100 component1 = dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
>                 component1.Name = "DataReader Source";
>                 component1.ComponentClassID = app.PipelineComponentInfos["DataReader Source"].CreationName;
>     }  
>   }  
> }
> ```

SQL 2019, VS 2019

On the same machine but this time in a "Script Task" in SSIS it doesn't work on the last line :

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: '"DataReader Source" does not exist in the collection "PipelineComponentInfos".

I have referenced the dlls  like in my console app, all versions are 15.0.0.0

For example :C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll

I added the reference on Microsoft.SqlServer.ADONETSrc, but no result.

I tried to use different versions of Mssql.Dts dlls without succes

Why this code runs in console app and not in a script task ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: From the Console version I get the list of available components, I have 53.  (foreach (PipelineComponentInfo item in _application.PipelineComponentInfos). From the script task, I have only 44. The dll **Microsoft.SqlServer.ADONETSrc** does not seem to be taken into account

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. My package containing the Task script was running in 32-bit mode in Visual Studio for compatibility reasons with some tasks. So I set the Run64BitRuntime mode to true and I now get all objects. In console mode I was indeed in 64 bits.

Question: would it be possible to obtain this result while remaining in 32 bits?